# difference between admin.conf and super-admin.conf in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I recently initiate kubernetes 1.29.0 and in the /etc/kubernetes/ path I found super-admin.conf file.
Does anyone know the difference between admin.conf and super-admin.conf?